# Can Tesseract 3.04.01 be compiled with VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, tesseract

I am trying to compile Tesseract 3.04.01 using Visual Studio 2010. Tesseract comes with a vs2010 sub-folder in its project root, which made me assume that it is meant to compile under it.

[image]

However, its source code makes use of variable-length arrays (VLA), which are definitely not supported in VS2010. For example this code:

```
static void AddIdTohOCR(STRING* hocr_str, const std::string base, int num1, int num2) {
  unsigned long bufsize = base.length() + 2 * kMaxIntSize;
  char id_buffer[bufsize];
```

Here `id_buffer[bufsize]` is a variable-length array.

So does anyone know if Tesseract 3.04.01 is meant to compile under VS2010? I'm thinking they might have just forgotten to delete the VS2010 project, or maybe they left it so it can be loaded into a newer version of Visual Studio. I tried with VS2012, but it failed on the same code as well, so it doesn't support VLA either.

Comment: Hi. Have solve your problem ? Did you compiled Tesseract with VS2010 ? If you do, can you help me to do the same ?

Comment: The accepted answer already explains everything. Did you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is probably just a few commits behind where they fixed it:

```
  const unsigned long BUFSIZE = 64;
  char id_buffer[BUFSIZE];
```

Comment: I found the commit, even the comment is `Fix varsize array for Microsoft compiler`.